# Handling multiple classes in a generic controller, some pointers please

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC3.

I have a pretty complex document class that contains many sub classes, lets call them "dog", "cat", "sheep", "cow", "goat".

I would like to use a generic controller to list, add and edit each of these classes.

Listing: I can list the relevant entity by passing in document model and iterating through the relevant class.

Edit: I need to get the id and identify the class of interest ie "dog" and then passing this as the model for editing. However next time round I may be editing a "cat" instance. Typically in MVC, as I understand it, one would ideally create a "DogController" and a "CatController". However since this document class is meant to be flexible I do not wish to hard code controllers. It may be necessary to add 2 more classes ie "horse" and "donkey".

At the moment I am using some if/else logic to ensure that the correct View is setup and called with the correct class. However this does feel as if I am breaking some MVC rules here.

Perhaps the answer lies in the use of a more formal ViewModel. Perhaps I can then have one of the properties as the subclass ("Dog"). Perhaps this can be swapped out at runtime using IOC?

Thoughts and pointers appreciated?

Thanks.

EDIT: I have tried to create 2 version of the "edit" action with different input models

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Dog DogModel){}

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Cat CatModel){}
```

I thought that due to method overloading MVC would be able to pick the correct one when the View posted, and then applied modelbinding.

Perhaps I am expecting too much or my understanding is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

```
routes.MapRoute("Route", "{controller}/{action}/{name}/{id}", new { controller = "Animal", action = "search", name = "Home", id = 0 });
```

Comment: Thanks, a little more detail would be appreciated. Thanks again

Comment: Aah, I have just understood...!!! I did not see your "Animal" bit. However I still have this issue where different "Dog", "Cat" models may be coming back from the View, and therefore one may need different action to handle these different input models/types. I did try and create 2 versions of the Edit Action thinking that the signature was different and therefore MVC would workout which one to use, like an overloaded method, but I cannot get this to work at present. See my edit above.

Comment: Just read up on overloading actions, not the same as methods. I will rename the actions for now, or use the "[ActionName]" attribute. But it is messy. I think there must be a much more eloquent solution. I am still thinking ViewModels, IOC etc, but cannot yet see the light.